# How not to show if there is same result occurs more than once- Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

**Scenario**

I have the code as below. My question is how to don't show appearing same result more than once.

```
male(charles).
male(andrew).
male(edward).

female(ann).

age(charles, 70).
age(ann, 65).
age(andrew, 60).
age(edward, 55). 

nextking(X) :- age(X,P), age(Y,Q),
               P>=Q, X\==Y;  age(X,55).
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**What I need**

I need the output to be charles, ann, andrew, edward. No repetition of names.

Comment: You mean I change the rule to `nextking(X) :- age(X,_)`? For that case, if i changed order of the facts, I won't get correct results. I need the query to display names based on descending order of age.

Comment: I don't understand the code much. Anyway the answer I am getting is not correct too. I am getting the answer as `edward, charles, ann, andrew`. The correct answer should be `charles, ann, andrew, edward` since that is the correct order in terms of descending of age.

Comment: *I don't understand the code much*. Did you write this code or did it come from somewhere else? In plain language, what is the condition for someone to be the "next king"? The code implies that the "next king" is anyone who is either at age 55, OR who is older than at least one other person. Based upon the existing data, that could be anyone.

Comment: The code I wrote myself. what I meant by I don't understand is the comment someone gave as `nextking(X) :- age(X,_)`. Now that comment is removed already by that person. I don't know how that solution can give a correct answer. That solution is just depends on the order of how I put my facts. Anyway I got the answer from another member in stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nextking/1` predicate is rather inefficient, and furthermore does not guarantee the persons to be sorted by age.

If we would for example put `charles` last in the list of facts, we get:

```
?- nextking(X).
X = ann ; 
X = ann ;
X = andrew ;
X = charles ;
X = charles ;
X = charles ;
X = edward.
```

basically te predicate you wrote has two clauses:

```
nextking(X) :-
    age(X,P),
    age(Y,Q),
    P >= Q,
    X\==Y.
nextking(X) :-
    age(X, 55).
```

The first simply will yield any `X` for which there exists a person `Y` that is younger. But that thus gives no guarantees that these elements are sorted. Finally the last predicate will unify with all persons `X` that are 55 years old. For this specific case this works, but it would mean if we state another fact `age(louise, 14)`, then this will fail. Not only is the approach incorrect, but even if it was correct it will be very "unstable".

We can make use of the [**`setof/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) predicate that does not only perform a uniqness filter, but also sorts the elements.

Since we want to sort the members of the royal family by descending age, we thus should construct 2-tuples (or an other structure that encapsulates the two parameters) where the first parameter contains the *negative* age, and the second parameter the corresponding person.

We can then use [**`member/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) to "unwind" the list in individual unifications:

```
nextking(X) :-
    setof((NA, X), A^(age(X, A), NA is -A), Royals),
    member((_, X), Royals).
```

This will produce the list of elements like:

```
?- nextking(X).
X = charles ;
X = ann ;
X = andrew ;
X = edward.
```

regardless how the facts are ordered in the source file.

Comment: Thank you Willem. This is perfect answer although I don't understand how it works. Need to learn further about it. Like you said, changing facts doesn't affect anything in my result. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

With a fairly recent version, you can use library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)):

```
?- distinct(nextking(X)).
X = charles ;
X = ann ;
X = andrew ;
X = edward.
```

or use the classic 'all solutions' builtin:

```
?- setof(K,K^nextking(K),Ks),member(X,Ks).
Ks = [andrew, ann, charles, edward],
X = andrew ;
Ks = [andrew, ann, charles, edward],
X = ann ;
...
```

but in this case, we loose the answer order defined by the KB.

Comment: I updated my question with more details about my requirement. Not sure if that is possible or not

Comment: seems the output produced by `distinct` already matches your required order, isn't it ?

Comment: Nope. when I use `distinct(nextking(X))`, it is only printing out one name. That is not what I need. It should display all the name in the descending order of age.

Comment: That's how Prolog works... it show *one* answer at time, press `;` to get more. It's reasonable, because what you want to do with all solutions is still unknown. In case you're happy with a list, just wrap the query with findall: `?- findall(X,distinct(nextking(X)),L).`

Comment: Oh yes...that is my silly mistake. I think I press `enter` too fast and thought is was showing only one name. With your `distinct` method, it is printing correctly. Just curious to know, for this case, once I turned on trace, I am seeing so many lines especially many with []. Do you know what does it do?

Comment: more or less... it keeps a cache of returned answers. But the details can be  complex, because terms could contain *variables*...

Comment: thank you for this answer. so `limit(1)` is a cut-less `once`? a very important thing to add to such library would be the *pure* diagonalization of solutions, or "fair scheduling" (or what's it called), so that every possible solution appears at a finite index in the produced stream of solutions (like they have in (mini-)Kanren).

Comment: this refers to an and-combination of goals, of course. or perhaps both and- and or- combinations. i.e. `cross_product(nats, nats)` having a pair `(i,j)` at a finite position, for any `i` and `j`.

Comment: @WillNess: I'm not sure that the purpose of solution_sequences is about determinacy, rather on efficiency and syntax. Indeed, as a relational language, Prolog is sorely missing such basic SQL facilities on aggregates.

Comment: also, I'm not sure if `*->` is considered pure. But if it is, `(limit(1,G) *-> ... ; ...)` would be a cut-less, *pure* cut (or `if`). Prolog is sorely missing the pure `if` first of all, as the existence of the *re-if* library demonstrates. or is the regular `once` already considered pure? I'm confused. :)

Comment: Soft cut is not purer that cut, though. That's at the root of language computational properties. library(reif) seems the way to go, but the implementation in Prolog is impossible, some extension is needed.